# How to update DOM between for loop iterations in svelte?

Tags: javascript, dom, svelte

I am using svelte to build a roulette board. My idea is to have a function `roll()` that, when clicked, will generate a random number between 50-100. The roll function will also iterate over each number of each roulette square and increase its font size to 20px ( to give off the impression a "ball" is rolling over that number ). However, my current program increases the font size of ALL numbers after the for loop is completed. I want each number to return back to its original font size before the next number's font size increase. I looked up solutions to this problem, and found that some have used `setTimeout1, but that solution never worked for me.

Here is my code

```js
let board = [
        {num: 35, color: "black"},
        {num: 3, color: "red"},
        {num: 26, color: "black"},
        {num: 0, color: "green"},
        {num: 32, color: "black"},
        {num: 15, color: "red"},
        {num: 19, color: "black"},
        {num: 4, color: "red"},
        {num: 21, color: "black"},
        {num: 2, color: "red"},
        {num: 25, color: "black"},
        {num: 17, color: "red"},
        {num: 34, color: "black"},
        {num: 6, color: "red"},
        {num: 27, color: "black"},
        {num: 13, color: "red"},
        {num: 36, color: "black"},
        {num: 11, color: "red"},
        {num: 30, color: "black"},
        {num: 8, color: "red"},
        {num: 23, color: "black"},
        {num: 10, color: "red"},
        {num: 5, color: "black"},
        {num: 24, color: "red"},
        {num: 16, color: "black"},
        {num: 33, color: "red"},
        {num: 1, color: "black"},
        {num: 20, color: "red"},
        {num: 14, color: "black"},
        {num: 31, color: "red"},
        {num: 9, color: "black"},
        {num: 22, color: "red"},
        {num: 18, color: "black"},
        {num: 29, color: "red"},
        {num: 9, color: "black"},
        {num: 7, color: "red"},
        {num: 28, color: "black"},
        {num: 12, color: "red"},
        ]


function roll(){
        let square = document.getElementById("square");
        for(let i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
            let number = document.getElementById("number"+[i]);
            number.style.fontSize = "20px"
        }
    }
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Roulette!</h1>
    <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row;">
        {#each board as c, i}
        <div class="{c.color}" id="square" style="flex:1" >
        <p id="number{i++}">{c.num}</p>
        </div>
      {/each}
    </div>
    <button on:click={roll}>Roll</button>
</main>

// for non-svelte users, this is simply creating a roulette board.
```

I am sure there is a better way to go about this, but I do not want to use jQuery or any libraries to do this.

The effect I am going for is a blinking iteration from one number to the next, but I am not sure how to make the DOM update after each iteration.

Comment: You shouldn't use a loop at all. Just a timer that works on a different number each time it runs. A loop runs so quickly that it's over before you even see anything.

Comment: I am not sure how I am suppose to use a timer without a loop when I want to iterate over a large amount of numbers.

Comment: A timer can be set up to call itself at regular intervals (`setInterval()`), this creates the looping action. Each time it runs, you just look at the next number by keeping a separate variable that keeps track of what number you are on.

Answer (score 2):

Using a loop when pauses are needed is a common mistake people make. Loops run incredibly fast. What you want is timings that (comparably) are much slower. So, don't use a loop at all and instead just use a timer that either calls itself recursively or an interval timer.

I don't know Svelt, so here's a modified example:

```js
// Get a reference to all the "numbers" just once
// not each timme the function is called
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll("div");

let timer = null; // Will hold reference to timer

function roll(){
  let wheelCounter = 0; // Will keep track of how many times around the wheel
  let counter = 0;      // Will keep track of which number we're on
  
  // Start a timer that will call its callback at regular intervals
  timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(wheelCounter < 3){
      // Remove the style from the last number (if there was a last number)
      if(counter > 0){
        numbers[counter - 1].classList.remove("active");
      }
  
      // Check to see if we should keep going
      if(counter < numbers.length){
        numbers[counter++].classList.add("active");  // Add the needed style
      } else {
        counter = 0; // Start iterating numbers over again
        wheelCounter++ // Adjust how many times around the wheel we've been
      }
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer); // Cancel the timer
    }
  }, 200);  // <-- Note the second argument to setInterval is a number of milliseconds to wait before calling the function again.
}

roll();
```

```css
div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:2px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin:3px;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:20px;
}

.active { background-color: #ff0; font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and yes this works and I can see why this would be better. I noticed that we call this function with `roll()`. I want the effect to repeat a few times because a roulette table makes a few revolutions before the ball hits its spot. I would usually make a wrapper function and put 3 `roll()` calls, but is there a better way to do this? I can’t say numbers.length * 3 because those locations are null. I guess I could wrap the whole thing in a `while` loop and make it run 3 times, and then have a 4th function to pick the random number, but again, I’m not sure if this is bad.

Comment: @ETHan I've updated my answer to show what you are asking about. Remember, you don't always need to go to a loop when you want something to happen repetitively - - the timer is already doing this for you, so it's just a simple matter of resetting the number counter back to the beginning when it hits the end and introducing another counter that gets incremented at that point. Please consider marking this as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tick`](https://svelte.dev/docs#tick) for this, where `tick` waits for the DOM to update.
I added the `highlighted` property which when set makes the number bold.

I also added the `sleep` function so you can introduce a delay easily.

Code

```
<script>

  import { tick } from "svelte";

  let board = [
    {num: 35, color: "black"},
    {num: 3, color: "red"},
    {num: 26, color: "black"},
    {num: 0, color: "green"},
    {num: 32, color: "black"},
    {num: 15, color: "red"},
    {num: 19, color: "black"},
    {num: 4, color: "red"},
  ];

  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  async function roll() {
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      board[i].highlighted = true;
      await tick();
      await sleep(500);
      board[i].highlighted = false;
      await tick();
      await sleep(500);
    }
  }
</script>

<main>
  <h1>Roulette!</h1>
  <div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row;">
    {#each board as c, i}
      <div class="{c.color}" id="square" style="flex:1">
        <p id="number{i++}" style="font-weight: { c.highlighted ? 'bold' : 'normal' };">{c.num}</p>
      </div>
    {/each}
  </div>
  <button on:click={roll}>Roll</button>
</main>
```

Notice the style tag, you can replace it with [`class:highlighted={c.highlighted}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#class_name), then add the `.highlighted` class to your css.

Generally with svelte, you can avoid touching the DOM directly in most cases.
Thinking about data is much easier than thinking about the DOM.
So in this case, setting a highlighted property of a board is easier than thinking about the necessary steps required to highlight a board in the DOM.

**Info: The above code does not work on the svelte repl because of the guard loop, an iteration must not exceed 100ms in the svelte repl.**
On [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shadow-q2w9z?file=/App.svelte), it works fine

Comment: I pasted that code in the Svelte REPL and I'm getting `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Infinite loop detected`.

Comment: @CarlosRoso download the repl and try it on your IDE. because on the repl, it doesn't work!

Comment: @CarlosRoso on Code Sandbox, it works correctly
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shadow-q2w9z?file=/App.svelte